# what is the differents between shell linux and mac osx shell?

Tags: linux, macos, shell

I have read and used a lot ubuntu linux shell but, before going to use a mac osx, I would know if shell bash commands and usages is the same for mac osx and linux distros, because both derive by unix system???

Comment: The default shell on OS X is bash 3.2 (due to Apple's refusal to ship software licensed GPLv3), whereas modern Linux distros all ship with bash 4.0 or newer -- so there are certainly built-in shell features you need to do without on OS X, until and unless you install your own version of the shell (which macports and similar tools make easy).

Comment: That said -- this is much more a usage question than a programming question, making SuperUser a more appropriate forum than StackOverflow.

Comment: thank you for your response, I keep it in mind, the last advice too.

Comment: See [this previous (closed) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051145/what-are-the-differences-between-using-the-terminal-on-a-mac-vs-linux).

Answer (score 2):

Both are POSIX compatible which means they comply with a particular set of standards. Wikipedia on POSIX: "POSIX defines the application programming interface (API), along with command line shells and utility interfaces, for software compatibility with variants of Unix and other operating systems."

However there are some commands that come bundled with ubuntu that are not present by default on OS X. For these you can usually get them from MacPorts.

In day to day use I don't find there to be much difference. The directory structure is not the same and OS X will litter your disk with .DS_Store files. But you could ssh into a remote machine and often not tell if it were Linux or OS X.