# Make linux SPLIT command compatible with Mac OS terminal

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I have a bash script that works fine in linux, but when I run it on my Mac terminal it fails, as the options for the `split`command are slightly different in Mac terminal. My script is:

```
## Merge and half final two segments
last_file=`ls temp_filt.snplist_* | tail -n 1`
penultimate_file=`ls temp_filt.snplist_* | tail -n 2 | head -1`
cat $penultimate_file $last_file > temp && mv temp $penultimate_file
split -n l/2 $penultimate_file && mv xaa $penultimate_file; mv xab $last_file
```

The script fails at the final line, since the `-n l/2` doesn't exist in `tcsh` (default shel environment in Mac OS 10.x.x). I was wondering what is the equivalent script in tcsh.

Is there a generic way to run linux script in Mac OS terminal, without the need to change the script?

Comment: `tcsh` hasn't been *the* default shell in Mac OS for over a decade (although it might be *your* default shell).

Comment: @chepner: Hi, so what it says here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8051196/5224239

Comment: Correct; you may still have `tcsh` as your login shell if the account has persisted across multiple OS updates, but I would recommend switching to `bash` (or at least something POSIX-compatible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use the language built-ins and limit external commands

Note the script contains several flaws: `ls` is useless and parsing `ls` output is not safe

```
array=(temp_filt.snplist_*)
last_file=${array[ -1]}
penultimate_file=${array[ -2]}
```

If the files are big bash read built-in will be very slow.

A simple solution in this case using `cat`, `wc`, `head` and `tail` which are compatible between systems. Note when passed in a command variables must be double quoted to avoid word splitting.

```
cat "$penultimate_file" "$last_file" > temp || exit 1
nb_lines=$(wc -l < temp)
((half_nb_lines=nb_lines/2))
head "-$half_nb_lines" temp > "$penultimate_file" || exit 1
tail "+$((half_nb_lines+1))" temp > "$last_file" || exit 1
rm temp
```

Note in the last line

```
command1 && command2 ; command3
```

the command3 is executed whatever the first exit status, { ; } may be used for grouping commands

```
command1 && { command2 ; command3; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, really helpful!

Answer (score 6):

It's not the MacOS terminal that's doing the `split`. It's a programm called `split`. MacOS is built on the FreeBSD userland tools, which behave differently from the GNU utils.

There are two options:

- Install the FreeBSD tools on your Linux boxes to make them compatible with FreeBSD.
- Install the GNU utils on your MacOS machine. If you have `brew` you can do this with `brew install coreutils`

Comment: `coreutils` doesn't replace the FreeBSD tools on MacOS, it adds them with a 'g' prefix. eg. `gsplit`

If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
  PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"